# What's the correct cost function for Linear Regression

Tags: machine-learning, linear-regression, cost-function, lasso, ridge-regression

As we all know the cost function for linear regression is:

[image]

Where as when we use Ridge Regression we simply add lambda*slope**2 but there I always seee the below as cost function of linear Regression where it's `not divided by the number of records`.:
[image]

So I just want to knows what's the correct cost function, Ik both are correct but while ding Ridge or Lasso why we ignore the division part?

Comment: This really depends on the implementation. The main difference between the two is that one optimizes the mean of squared deviations while the other optimizes the sum of squared deviations, which is practically the same.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Interesting question. I'd say it is correct not to divide, due to the following reasoning...

For linear regression there is no difference. The optimum of the cost function stays the same, regardless how it is scaled.

When doing Ridge or Lasso, the division affects the relative importance between the least-squares and the regularization parts of the cost function. We typically use regularization to avoid overfitting if there is not enough data. The more data we have, the less we want regularization affect our model. By *not* dividing, the least-squares term dominates the regularization term if there are many records.

In short, with constant lambda:

- With division, the optimum of the cost function is more or less independent of the number of records, which is not what we want, normally.
- Without division, the optimum of the cost function approaches the true parameters with increasing number of records.

To illustrate, I computed cost functions of a simple linear regression with ridge regularization and a true slope of 1.

If we divide by the number of records, the optimum stays below the true slope, even for a large number of records:
[image]

Without the division, the optimum approaches the true slope:
[image]

```py
import numpy as np
import scipy.optimize as spo
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

np.random.seed(123)


def make_data(n, noise=0.2):
    x = np.random.randn(n)
    y = x + noise * np.random.randn(n)
    return x, y


def cost(w, lam, x, y, divide_by_n=False):
    y_hat = w[:, None] * x[None, :]    
    least_squares = np.sum((y_hat - y)**2, axis=1)
    ridge = lam * w**2
    
    factor = 0.5/len(x) if divide_by_n else 1
    return ridge + least_squares * factor
    


w = np.linspace(0, 2)

for do_div in [True, False]:
    plt.figure()
    for n in [10, 100, 1000]:
        plt.plot(w, cost(w, 5, *make_data(10), divide_by_n=do_div), label=f"n={n}")
    
    plt.xlabel('weight')
    plt.ylabel('cost')
    plt.legend()
    plt.title(f'divide by N = {do_div}')
```

Comment: Ohh this makes sense, thank you so much for clear explainantion. Everyone whom I asked this question used to think that, it's a stupid question.